# (condition for) real eigenvalues of an oblique rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, rotations, matrix-decomposition

Let $A=$ $\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\beta) \\
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\beta) \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

If $\alpha =\beta$ then it is an orthogonal rotation and there are no real eigenvalues.

I cannot easily derive a nice rule for $A$ to have real eigenvalues when $\alpha \ne\beta$.

I am quite confident that when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have a different sign, the matrix must have real eigenvalues.

But I get stuck in the geometric formulas.
I would be glad if someone could point me to a source or just post a nice derivation.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague Johan D. confirmed the calculation does not lead to a straightforward formula. I copy his calculation below:

$\det{\left(A-\lambda I\right)}=\left|\begin{matrix}\cos{\alpha}-\lambda&-\sin{\beta}\\+\sin{\alpha}&\cos{\beta-\lambda}\\\end{matrix}\right|=0$

$\left(\cos{\alpha}-\lambda\right)\left(\cos{\beta-\lambda}\right)-\sin{\alpha}\left(-\sin{\beta}\right)=0$

$\left(\cos{\alpha}-\lambda\right)\left(\cos{\beta-\lambda}\right)+\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}=0$

$\lambda^2-\left(\cos{\alpha}+\cos{\beta}\right)\lambda+\ \cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}+\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}=0$

$D=b^2-4ac=\left(\cos{\alpha}+\cos{\beta}\right)^2-4\left(\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}+\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\right)$

$A$ has real eigenvalues
if and only if 
$D=\left(\cos{\alpha}+\cos{\beta}\right)^2-4\left(\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}+\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\right)\geq0$

In general: $\left(\cos{\alpha}-\cos{\beta}\right)^2\geq4\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}$

If $sgn\left(\sin{\alpha}\right)\neq sgn\left(\sin{\beta}\right)$ then $\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\le0$ , hence
$\left(\cos{\alpha}-\cos{\beta}\right)^2\geq0\geq4\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}$

so if $sgn\left(\sin{\alpha}\right)\neq sgn\left(\sin{\beta}\right)$, $A$ always has real eigenvalues

Comment: A linear transformation can be constructed using a scaling and an oblique rotation.

Some more info on oblique linear transformations can be found on:

[A general transformation as an oblique rotation and a scaling][1]

The reasoning in the answer above can also be found on:

[Eigenvalues of an oblique rotation][2]


  [1]: https://www.heavisidesdinner.com/LTFM/LTFM_book.html#tfmasobliquerotationandscaling
  [2]: https://www.heavisidesdinner.com/LTFM/LTFM_book.html#eigenvobliquerotation